# Javac errors when compiling pixel recognition script

Tags: java, image, colors, awt, awtrobot

Well J Barclay cleared up all but one of my problems!! yay!!

non-static method getRGB() cannot be referenced from a static context.

line 28-

new code-

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.Robot;
    import java.awt.AWTException;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class GunningBot{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    Robot robot = new Robot();
Color color = new Color(195, 174, 196);

{
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1075, 700);

    {
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    search: for(int x = 0; x < rectangle.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < rectangle.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            if(image.getRGB(x, y) == Color.getRGB())
            {
                robot.mouseMove(x, y);
                break search;
            }
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you're accessing an instance method on the class Robot instead of an instance of robot.

just change the case and it will be fixed:

```
BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
```

The issue with `Color.getRGB(195, 174, 196)` is that it is a getter, it has no parameters. The way to call this method is:

```
color.getRGB();
```

but again, you're using accessing an instance method without an instance, what you need to do is:

```
Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
color.getRGB();
```

Comment: Thank you that cleared up all but one error. and it has to do with the RGB deal which i cant seem to get strait

Comment: Re-read what I've suggested for accessing "color.getRGB()" - notice the lower case. You need to access the instance, not the class.